# changing keyboard return key label text

Tags: ios, user-interface

Iphone's onscreen keyboard has a number of predefined labels for its return key: done, return, go, google, etc. In my case I just want it to say Save, but it's not in the list. How can I create my own?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. UIKeyboard is read-only.